# Blocked IPs in iptables but DDOS still is going on

Tags: iptables, ddos

I had a DDOS today on a webserver running debian sequeeze and blocked various IP-Adresses in iptables like so:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 169.50.5.42 -j DROP
```

But it seems to not being dropping the traffic from these ip.

Listing all rules with iptables -L gives the following output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh 
fail2ban-pureftpd  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ftp 
fail2ban-dovecot-pop3imap  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports pop3,pop3s,imap2,imaps 
DROP       all  --  169.50.5.42-static.reverse.softlayer.com  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  169.50.5.45-static.reverse.softlayer.com  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  169.50.5.37-static.reverse.softlayer.com  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  169.50.5.36-static.reverse.softlayer.com  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  169.50.5.38-static.reverse.softlayer.com  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  169.50.5.39-static.reverse.softlayer.com  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  169.50.5.45-static.reverse.softlayer.com  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  169.50.5.42-static.reverse.softlayer.com  anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-dovecot-pop3imap (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-pureftpd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  43.229.53.60         anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Is there something that i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer myself. Apparently it needs some time to apply all changes internally. After one minute or so the rules are working.